# How can i get and save a value from an entry if i use grid?(tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

How can i get a value from an entry if i use grid?

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Test")
window.geometry(600x600)
window.config()

e = Entry(window, width=20).grid(row=0, column=1)

entry = e.get()

print(entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `.grid()` down on a separate line

```py
entry = Entry(window, width=20)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

print(entry)
```

BTW, you should have searched this site. I am sure there are millions like this

Comment: The `entry = e.get()` is useless and might confuse OP. Please remove it.